# Gapi analytics ext undefined (js)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api, google-api-js-client

I am trying to use the google analytics api (javascript) to display some charts (combined to charts.js).

I followed instructions here : [tuto gapi](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/third-party-visualizations/)

I created an application and I replaced my clientId in the code but I have the error :

> gapi.analytics.ext is undefined

Here is my code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        (function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
            g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
            js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
            fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
        }(window,document,'script'));
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="embed-api-auth-container"></div>
    <div id="view-selector-container"></div>
    <div id="active-users-container"></div>
    <div id="chart-1-container"></div>
    <div id="legend-1-container"></div>
    <div id="chart-2-container"></div>
    <div id="legend-2-container"></div>
    <div id="chart-3-container"></div>
    <div id="legend-3-container"></div>
    <div id="chart-4-container"></div>
    <div id="legend-4-container"></div>

    <!-- This demo uses the Chart.js graphing library and Moment.js to do date
         formatting and manipulation. -->
    <script src="/public/javascript/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/public/javascript/moment.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include the ViewSelector2 component script. -->
    <script src="/public/javascript/embed-api/components/view-selector2.js"></script>

    <!-- Include the DateRangeSelector component script. -->
    <script src="/public/javascript/embed-api/components/date-range-selector.js"></script>

    <!-- Include the ActiveUsers component script. -->
    <script src="/public/javascript/embed-api/components/active-users.js"></script>

    <script>

        // == NOTE ==
        // This code uses ES6 promises. If you want to use this code in a browser
        // that doesn't supporting promises natively, you'll have to include a polyfill.

        gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

            /**
             * Authorize the user immediately if the user has already granted access.
             * If no access has been created, render an authorize button inside the
             * element with the ID "embed-api-auth-container".
             */
            gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
                container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
                clientid: 'XXXXX-1rf6kc7cp47evmu7209i7d6famgbh1pq.apps.googleusercontent.com'
            });

            /**
             * Create a new ActiveUsers instance to be rendered inside of an
             * element with the id "active-users-container" and poll for changes every
             * five seconds.
             */
            var activeUsers = new gapi.analytics.ext.ActiveUsers({
                container: 'active-users-container',
                pollingInterval: 5
            });


            /**
             * Add CSS animation to visually show the when users come and go.
              */
            activeUsers.once('success', function() {
                var element = this.container.firstChild;
                var timeout;

                this.on('change', function(data) {
                    var element = this.container.firstChild;
                    var animationClass = data.delta > 0 ? 'is-increasing' : 'is-decreasing';
                    element.className += (' ' + animationClass);

                    clearTimeout(timeout);
                    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                        element.className =
                                element.className.replace(/ is-(increasing|decreasing)/g, '');
                    }, 3000);
                });
            });


            /**
             * Create a new ViewSelector2 instance to be rendered inside of an
             * element with the id "view-selector-container".
             */
            var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ext.ViewSelector2({
                container: 'view-selector-container',
            })
                    .execute();


            /**
             * Update the activeUsers component, the Chartjs charts, and the dashboard
             * title whenever the user changes the view.
             */
            viewSelector.on('viewChange', function(data) {
                var title = document.getElementById('view-name');
                title.innerHTML = data.property.name + ' (' + data.view.name + ')';

                // Start tracking active users for this view.
                activeUsers.set(data).execute();

                // Render all the of charts for this view.
                renderWeekOverWeekChart(data.ids);
                renderYearOverYearChart(data.ids);
                renderTopBrowsersChart(data.ids);
                renderTopCountriesChart(data.ids);
            });


            /**
             * Draw the a chart.js line chart with data from the specified view that
             * overlays session data for the current week over session data for the
             * previous week.
             */
            function renderWeekOverWeekChart(ids) {

                // Adjust `now` to experiment with different days, for testing only...
                var now = moment(); // .subtract(3, 'day');

                var thisWeek = query({
                    'ids': ids,
                    'dimensions': 'ga:date,ga:nthDay',
                    'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
                    'start-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'day').day(0).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                    'end-date': moment(now).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                });

                var lastWeek = query({
                    'ids': ids,
                    'dimensions': 'ga:date,ga:nthDay',
                    'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
                    'start-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'day').day(0).subtract(1, 'week')
                            .format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                    'end-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'day').day(6).subtract(1, 'week')
                            .format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                });

                Promise.all([thisWeek, lastWeek]).then(function(results) {

                    var data1 = results[0].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[2]; });
                    var data2 = results[1].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[2]; });
                    var labels = results[1].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[0]; });

                    labels = labels.map(function(label) {
                        return moment(label, 'YYYYMMDD').format('ddd');
                    });

                    var data = {
                        labels : labels,
                        datasets : [
                            {
                                label: 'Last Week',
                                fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                                data : data2
                            },
                            {
                                label: 'This Week',
                                fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                                strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                                pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                                data : data1
                            }
                        ]
                    };

                    new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-1-container')).Line(data);
                    generateLegend('legend-1-container', data.datasets);
                });
            }


            /**
             * Draw the a chart.js bar chart with data from the specified view that
             * overlays session data for the current year over session data for the
             * previous year, grouped by month.
             */
            function renderYearOverYearChart(ids) {

                // Adjust `now` to experiment with different days, for testing only...
                var now = moment(); // .subtract(3, 'day');

                var thisYear = query({
                    'ids': ids,
                    'dimensions': 'ga:month,ga:nthMonth',
                    'metrics': 'ga:users',
                    'start-date': moment(now).date(1).month(0).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                    'end-date': moment(now).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                });

                var lastYear = query({
                    'ids': ids,
                    'dimensions': 'ga:month,ga:nthMonth',
                    'metrics': 'ga:users',
                    'start-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'year').date(1).month(0)
                            .format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                    'end-date': moment(now).date(1).month(0).subtract(1, 'day')
                            .format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                });

                Promise.all([thisYear, lastYear]).then(function(results) {
                    var data1 = results[0].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[2]; });
                    var data2 = results[1].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[2]; });
                    var labels = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',
                        'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

                    // Ensure the data arrays are at least as long as the labels array.
                    // Chart.js bar charts don't (yet) accept sparse datasets.
                    for (var i = 0, len = labels.length; i < len; i++) {
                        if (data1[i] === undefined) data1[i] = null;
                        if (data2[i] === undefined) data2[i] = null;
                    }

                    var data = {
                        labels : labels,
                        datasets : [
                            {
                                label: 'Last Year',
                                fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                data : data2
                            },
                            {
                                label: 'This Year',
                                fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                                strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                                data : data1
                            }
                        ]
                    };

                    new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-2-container')).Bar(data);
                    generateLegend('legend-2-container', data.datasets);
                })
                        .catch(function(err) {
                            console.error(err.stack);
                        })
            }


            /**
             * Draw the a chart.js doughnut chart with data from the specified view that
             * show the top 5 browsers over the past seven days.
             */
            function renderTopBrowsersChart(ids) {

                query({
                    'ids': ids,
                    'dimensions': 'ga:browser',
                    'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
                    'sort': '-ga:pageviews',
                    'max-results': 5
                })
                        .then(function(response) {

                            var data = [];
                            var colors = ['#4D5360','#949FB1','#D4CCC5','#E2EAE9','#F7464A'];

                            response.rows.forEach(function(row, i) {
                                data.push({ value: +row[1], color: colors[i], label: row[0] });
                            });

                            new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-3-container')).Doughnut(data);
                            generateLegend('legend-3-container', data);
                        });
            }


            /**
             * Draw the a chart.js doughnut chart with data from the specified view that
             * compares sessions from mobile, desktop, and tablet over the past seven
             * days.
             */
            function renderTopCountriesChart(ids) {
                query({
                    'ids': ids,
                    'dimensions': 'ga:country',
                    'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
                    'sort': '-ga:sessions',
                    'max-results': 5
                })
                        .then(function(response) {

                            var data = [];
                            var colors = ['#4D5360','#949FB1','#D4CCC5','#E2EAE9','#F7464A'];

                            response.rows.forEach(function(row, i) {
                                data.push({
                                    label: row[0],
                                    value: +row[1],
                                    color: colors[i]
                                });
                            });

                            new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-4-container')).Doughnut(data);
                            generateLegend('legend-4-container', data);
                        });
            }


            /**
             * Extend the Embed APIs `gapi.analytics.report.Data` component to
             * return a promise the is fulfilled with the value returned by the API.
             * @param {Object} params The request parameters.
             * @return {Promise} A promise.
             */
            function query(params) {
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    var data = new gapi.analytics.report.Data({query: params});
                    data.once('success', function(response) { resolve(response); })
                            .once('error', function(response) { reject(response); })
                            .execute();
                });
            }


            /**
             * Create a new canvas inside the specified element. Set it to be the width
             * and height of its container.
             * @param {string} id The id attribute of the element to host the canvas.
             * @return {RenderingContext} The 2D canvas context.
             */
            function makeCanvas(id) {
                var container = document.getElementById(id);
                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                container.innerHTML = '';
                canvas.width = container.offsetWidth;
                canvas.height = container.offsetHeight;
                container.appendChild(canvas);

                return ctx;
            }


            /**
             * Create a visual legend inside the specified element based off of a
             * Chart.js dataset.
             * @param {string} id The id attribute of the element to host the legend.
             * @param {Array.<Object>} items A list of labels and colors for the legend.
             */
            function generateLegend(id, items) {
                var legend = document.getElementById(id);
                legend.innerHTML = items.map(function(item) {
                    var color = item.color || item.fillColor;
                    var label = item.label;
                    return '<li><i style="background:' + color + '"></i>' + label + '</li>';
                }).join('');
            }


            // Set some global Chart.js defaults.
            Chart.defaults.global.animationSteps = 60;
            Chart.defaults.global.animationEasing = 'easeInOutQuart';
            Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
            Chart.defaults.global.maintainAspectRatio = false;

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how to configure my app? 
Did I do someting wrong?

Thanks for help !